# Handling multiple currencies in Java app

Tags: java

I want to be able to handle multiple currencies in my app. I have a method that will create a transaction instance:

```
class MyApp() {
    //...
    public Transaction createTransaction(String desc, BigDecimal amount) {...
```

So called something like this:

```
createTransaction("Phone bill", new BigDecimal("28.555"));
```

However I want the amount to be formatted depending on what the currency/ locale is set to. I was thinking to have something like:

```
interface MyCurrency() {
    public static BigDecimal format(BigDecimal amount);
}

public class GBP implements MyCurrency {
    public static BigDecimal format(BigDecimal amount) {
        return amount.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR); // 28.555 -> 28.55
    }
}

public class JPY implements MyCurrency {
    public static BigDecimal format(BigDecimal amount) {
        return amount.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR); // 28.555 -> 28
    }
}

// then modify my app class as follows

class MyApp() {
    //...
    public void setCurrency(MyCurrency currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }
    public Transaction createTransaction(String desc, BigDecimal amount) {
        amount = this.currency.format(amount);
        //...
    }
```

I hope this makes sense. But, is there a Java build in way of doing this? I searched for handling multiple currencies, but didn't find anything that discussed this (I'm sure it's a pretty common scenario though)

Comment: Keep this in mind: There's not really any such thing as a unit-less number.  If you're creating a transaction, you need to be specifying what currency (the unit) the transaction is in.  You need to store that information everywhere, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following? It formats the currency according to the number specifications of the country you're displaying it in.

```
java.util.Currency usd = java.util.Currency.getInstance("USD");
java.text.NumberFormat format = java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(java.util.Locale.GERMANY);
format.setCurrency(usd);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(usd.getDefaultFractionDigits());
System.out.println(format.format(23));
```

Unless you mean, in germany it should be euros, in UK it should be pounds. in that case you should clarify your question.

But if that's the case:

```
DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format( 123.45);//    $123.45
DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY).format( 123.45); // 123,45 €
```